# Can the alert keyboard be used for any text field on iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, keyboard

I am developing my first iOS app and I really like the look of the alert keyboard. I was wondering if I can use it for any page or if there is a specific reason for it? I do not want my first app to be rejected for something this unimportant, but it would be a nice add on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use it for anything you want, alert is nothing more than a keyboard style and there is absolutely nothing in place that tells you what you can and can not use it for.

```
[myTextField setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
```