# UISearchBar keyboard appearance

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, uisearchbar

According to this question, we can change keyboard appearance of any UITextField in iOS [Can the alert keyboard be used for any text field on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311376/can-the-alert-keyboard-be-used-for-any-text-field-on-ios)

But what about the UISearchBar? Is there a way for that, because `[searchBarInstance setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];` doesn't work, since UISearchBar lacks of this method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do like this,

```
for(UIView *subView in searchBar.subviews)
  if([subView isKindOfClass: [UITextField class]])
    [(UITextField *)subView setKeyboardAppearance: UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
```

see [iPhone UISearchBar & keyboardAppearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767470/iphone-uisearchbar-keyboardappearance)

Comment: Thank you, haven't found that question!